# Add a new O365 users to AD group using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I'm using a Powershell script to add new users to O365 and assign multiple licenses. However i'm now  trying to also add the new user to existing groups.

**Powershell**

```
Connect-MsolService -Credential $UserCredential
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Jesse\Documents\Powershell\NewAccounts.csv" | foreach {New-MsolUser -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -UsageLocation $_.UsageLocation -LicenseAssignment $_.AccountSkuIdEMS,$_.AccountSkuIdENTERPRISEPACK} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Jesse\Documents\Powershell\NewAccountResults.csv" -Verbose
```

**.CSV**

```
DisplayName,FirstName,LastName,UserPrincipalName,Usagelocation,AccountSkuIdEMS, AccountSkuIdENTERPRISEPACK
Test Jesse,Test,Jesse,test.jesse@(Tenant).nl,NL,(Tenant):EMS,(Tenant):ENTERPRISEPACK
```

I've found the following code, but wouldn't know how to correctly implement it into my existing code. I think i would also need to connect to a new service to use this cmdlet. is it possible to switch between connections within a single script?

```
Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity "Azure AD Join" -LinkType Members -Links test.jesse@(tenant).nl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AzureAD Module cmd [Add-AzureADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0) to add the new user to existing groups.

Remember to install AzureAD Module by following [Azure Active Directory PowerShell for Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0).

You can reuse the `$Credential` for AzureAD Module in Powershell. It won't require you to login again.

Here is my sample for your reference:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential

Connect-MsolService -Credential $Credential

Import-Csv -Path "E:\test\NewAccounts.csv" | foreach {New-MsolUser -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -UsageLocation $_.UsageLocation} | Export-Csv -Path "E:\test\NewAccountResults.csv"

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential

$newusers = Import-Csv -Path "E:\test\NewAccounts.csv" | foreach {Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$($_.UserPrincipalName)'"}

foreach ($user in $newusers){
    Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "{object id of the existing group}" -RefObjectId $user.ObjectId
}
```

BTW, you can get **the object id of the existing group** from Azure portal.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

If i wanted to add multiple groups at once to the user. How should i proceed?